# Could “un coup de vin” mean “a glass of wine”?

Tags: sens

I would like to confirm whether the “coups de vin” in the excerpt below refer to a few glasses to wine, as I decided in the end, or just to a few sips of wine, as I initially thought. How modest was the merchant?

The excerpt is from [« La Belle et la Bête »](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/La_Belle_et_la_B%C3%AAte) by M-me de Beaumond:

> Le marchand attacha son cheval dans l’écurie, et marcha vers la maison, où il ne trouva personne ; mais, étant entré dans une grande salle, il y trouva un bon feu, et une table chargée de viande, où il n’y avait qu’un couvert. Comme la pluie et la neige l’avaient mouillé jusqu’aux os, il s’approcha du feu pour se sécher, et disait en lui-même : le maître de la maison ou ses domestiques me pardonneront la liberté que j’ai prise, et sans doute ils viendront bientôt. Il attendit pendant un tems considérable ; mais onze heures ayant sonné, sans qu’il vit personne, il ne put résister à la faim, et prit un poulet qu’il mangea en deux bouchées, et en tremblant. **Il but aussi quelques coups de vin**, et, devenu plus hardi, il sortit de la salle, et traversa plusieurs grands appartemens, magnifiquement meublés.

I know that “une coupe de vin” refers to a glass of wine. But the word “coup” was used, and I did check the source page: that was not a typo.

Thank you very much. Answers in French are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pas de lien avec *coupe*, un *coup* est ici une gorgée. L'expression utilisée ici est idiomatique:

> boire un coup

[TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/coup):

> 2. P. méton.
>      a) Quantité de liquide (et notamment de vin) qu'on peut boire assez rapidement en une seule fois. *J'ai dû boire un coup de trop ?* (Pourrat, Gaspard,1922, p. 72):

Comment: Peut-être que c'est utile de présenter le regroupement « C. Avec une idée de promptitude, de vivacité » (par opposition au _mouvement suivi d'un choc_ (A.) et au _mouvement simple_ (B.) au lexique). Merci !

Comment: This. Personally this is the first time I see the expression in the plural, though. Nowadays it seems to be a lot more common in the singular.

Comment: Quelle honte, je n'ai pas vu cette partie de l'article la première foi… Merci beaucoup!

Comment: This expression can be found in other contexts, arguably more rarely though: "manger un coup" (eat something), "passer un coup d'eau" (to give a rinse), and of course -pardon me- "péter un coup" (to leave a fart).